# Call a LUA function in string in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have a C++ load function from a string. Then I want recall this function from lua but have error : "call attempt global exm function...". How I can recall this in lua file
In C++ file:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>






  int __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl luaopen_newtool (lua_State* L) {
        static const char * lua_code = "function exm()\n return true\n end";

        luaL_dostring(L ,(const char *)lua_code);
        return 0;
}


}
```

And in LUA file:

```
require("newtool")
local exam = exm()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/STUBqLicl66pofjR